# How to Unbrick Android Phone Which has No OS, No Recovery? and How to Repair IMEI in MTK Devices?

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, fastboot, unbricking, micromax

> I think i bricked my phone, my phones model number is "Micromax Canvas
>   Spark Q380".
>
> I've no OS installed, No Recovery Mode Installed.
>
> Also fastboot and adb can't recognise my device on PC.
>
> I've tried this :
>   http://forum.xda-developers.com/gene...k-rom-t3131362 but it also
>   didn't worked.
>
> What to do?? any help please

Comment: Can you hear a sound when you connect the phone to computer?

Comment: yes i do but when do process of fastboot, then it says mp device found.

Comment: I don't get you there! You said no OS, no recovery, so the phone is not powering on, or if so, it is stuck in the splash screen, right?

Comment: it also not displaying splash screen. :(

Comment: its just blank, or dead.

Comment: Ok since you can hear a sound, this means there is a chance to revive your phone

Comment: ok so, what should i do??

Comment: Your phone's specs say it is powered by Mediatek chip (MT6582M). We need to find if the preloader is still present.

Comment: so how to find that??

Comment: check my answer and let me know if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For IMEI repairing on MTK devices, you'll need a tool called `MAUI META 3G` and `BPLGU modem file`

This [tutorial](https://devs-lab.com/permanent-imei-fix-for-mtk-6582.html) explains it better.

Answer (score 2):

Unbricking MTK devices is quite simple. You need the stock firmware and the flashtool.

- Download the firmware [here](http://bit.ly/1TuTgn4)
- SP Flashtool (the tool needed to flash the files)
- Extract firmware zip file (I think the flashtool may be inside. If not, download it from [here](http://spflashtool.com/)
- Install USB Drivers. ([VCOM or META drivers needed, get them here](https://androidmtk.com/download-mtk-usb-all-drivers))
- Open SP Flash Tool and click the Download tab button, select “Firmware upgrade” .
- Click Scatter-Loading button & browse to the extracted firmware folder and select MT6582M_Android_scatter.txt file (It is a map file that tells the computer where each files can be sent in the phone)
- Now hit the Download button.
- Connect your phone to the PC with battery inside by USB cable (Drivers shall be installed)
- After the flashing process succeed, a green tick will appear. Disconnect your phone and power it up.

Done.

Comment: Ahhh !!! I was skipped to install mediatek drivers, now i installed it and my phone is working like a charm. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad that I helped :)

Comment: hey wait, all is working fine but my sim is not showing its network. Its in a emergency call only mode.

Comment: Check if IMEI is present *#06#

Comment: No its not, It says "invalid".

Comment: Ok, you need to repair it.

Comment: Guide Me Bro !!

Comment: As the phone is alive now, edit your question by adding the issue so that I can add another answer with the IMEI repair process

Comment: Done, Go Ahead.

Comment: First, tell me what is the contents of the unzipped folder, the one containing thr flash files? There should be some files witj another folder

Comment: there are only flash files there.

Comment: there is not another folder amongst those files?